# C++ no operator matches these operands

Tags: c++, file-io, operator-keyword, operands

I copy/paste this console application, which is a banking record keeping system, and I get an error for the ">" operator not having operands; `if (infile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(this), sizeof(*this)) > 0)`

Does it have something to do with types? I read vaguely somewhere about the `int` needing to be overloaded or something. Anyways, idk.

Here is part of the code:

```
void account_query::read_rec()
{
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open("record.bank", ios::binary);
    if (!infile)
    {
        cout << "Error in Opening! File Not Found!!" << endl;
        return;
    }
    cout << "\n****Data from file****" << endl;
    while (!infile.eof())
    {
        if (infile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(this), sizeof(*this)) > 0)
        {
            show_data();
        }
    }
    infile.close();
```

Comment: `while (!infile.eof())` Read here please: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons

Comment: Regarding your error, take a look ar `read()` return type in the docs please: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read

Answer (score 1):

[`ifstream::read()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read) does not return the number of characters read. It returns a reference to itself.

Also, dont use `while (!infile.eof())`: [Why is `iostream::eof()` inside a loop condition (i.e. `while (!stream.eof())`) considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons)

Instead, test if the `ifstream` is in a good state after reading from it. This can done with:

```
if(infile) { ... }
```

Since `infile.read(...)` returns a reference to `infile`, this could be a possible fix:

```
cout << "\n****Data from file****" << endl;
while (infile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(this), sizeof(*this)))
    show_data();
}
```